# Can I use a Tomcat Valve with Jetty?

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty, tomcat-valve

Is it possible to use a Valve for Tomcat also together with Jetty? If yes how can I set it up with jetty.xml and/or embedded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Valve is a Tomcat-specific thing, not part of Servlet specification. However, you can share filters.